# Terraform Azure subscription lz-vending subscription_id

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I want to integrate another terraform module with lz_vending to create budget and budget alerts. this module has subscription_id as one of its variables and I will call this modules within lz-vending as a root module. how can I get this value while subscription_id will be created after terraform apply and is needed at the same time for budget creation?

I am thinking of using subscription_id output as a value in my cost management module for subscription_id variable will this help? and if someone tried this before how did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to provision Azure subscription lz-vending subscription_id by calling this modules within lz-vending as a root module and I was able to provision the requirement successfully

This configuration module requires new  `subscription_id` for creating budgets and alerts. However, this `subscription_id` is generated only after applying the Terraform configuration.

Consider using the output of `subscription_id` from `lz_vending` as an input to your new module.

In your new module, you can reference this output value. Terraform will automatically handle the dependency and ensure that `lz_vending` is applied before your module

**My file structure for this configuration:**

```
terraform-project/
│
├── main.tf
└── modules/
    ├── lz_vending/
    │     ├── main.tf
    └── budget_alerts/
          ├── main.tf
```

**main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "lz_vending" {
  source = "./modules/lz_vending"
}

module "budget_alerts" {
  source = "./modules/budget_alerts"
  subscription_id = module.lz_vending.subscription_id
}
```

**modules/lz_vending/main.tf**

```
resource "random_pet" "subscription" {
  length = 2
}

output "subscription_id" {
  value = "/subscriptions/${random_pet.subscription.id}"
  description = "The ID of the created subscription in Azure format"
}
```

**modules/budget_alerts/main.tf**:

```
resource "azurerm_consumption_budget_subscription" "budget" {
  name            = "demovk-budget"
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  amount          = 100
  time_grain = "Monthly"

  # Corrected time_period block
  time_period {
    start_date = "2023-11-01T00:00:00Z"
    end_date   = "2023-12-01T00:00:00Z"
  }

  # Updated notification configuration
  notification {
    contact_emails = ["admin@example.com"]
    threshold      = 80
    threshold_type = "Actual"
    operator       = "GreaterThan"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did try this solution but I couldn't create the budget. I got this error: │  134:   subscription_id     = module.lz_vending.subscription_id
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for
│ module.budget_and_alerts.var.subscription_id declared at
│ modules/budget_and_alerts/variables.tf:17,1-27: string required. Did you  face this error before and came across the problem?